# Sort an array by value and index in C

Tags: c, sorting

> Your task is to sort an array of integer numbers by the product of the
>   value and the index of the positions.
>
> For sorting the index starts at 1, NOT at 0! The sorting has to be
>   ascending. The array will never be null and will always contain
>   numbers.

My solution

```
int* sortByValueAndIndex(int* array, int arrayLength) {
  int* extraArray = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int)); 

  for (int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++) {
    extraArray[index] = array[index] * (index + 1);
  }

  /* Bubble sort */
  for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < arrayLength - 1; firstIndex++) {
    for (int secondIndex = 0; secondIndex < arrayLength - firstIndex - 1; secondIndex++) {
      if (extraArray[secondIndex] > extraArray[secondIndex + 1]) {

        int tmp = array[secondIndex];
        array[secondIndex] = array[secondIndex + 1];
        array[secondIndex + 1] = tmp;

        tmp = extraArray[secondIndex];
        extraArray[secondIndex] = extraArray[secondIndex + 1];
        extraArray[secondIndex + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  free(extraArray);

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code works, though it needs \$O(n)\$ space and \$O(n^2)\$ time.

It's also quite cleanly implemented, so kudos.

Still, there's naturally something which can be improved:

1. If you need a generic loop-index, the natural name is `i`. If you need a second one, ask for `j`. Yes, they are short, but they are **the** standard names, so you cannot get more descriptive.
2. Your additional array's name should reflect its use: Call it `keys`.
3. You have a general tendency for long names. Try to keep it as brief as you can without sacrificing clarity.
4. Avoid using a type with `sizeof`. If the receiving variable ever changes its type, you have to keep it in sync manually, and its not idiomatic. Use:

   ```
   int* keys = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof *keys);
   ```
5. You assume that `malloc()` won't fail. You know *assume* makes an *ass* out of *u* and *me*?
6. Do you know that signed integer-overflow is Undefined Behavior? I didn't find anywhere in the problem-description a guarantee that `array[i] * (i + 1)` won't overflow, so you might want to use a bigger type for the keys.
7. Should you really write your own sub-standard sorting-algorithm, or can you use the one in the standard-library?

The following trades more extra-space for using `qsort()`, which should have \$O(n * \log(n))\$ runtime:

```
typedef struct pair {
    long long key;
    int value;
} pair;

static int sortByValueAndIndex_comp(const void* pa, const void* pb) {
    long long a = ((pair*)pa)->key;
    long long b = ((pair*)pb)->key;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int* sortByValueAndIndex(int* arr, int n) {
    assert(arr || !n);
    assert(INT_MAX <= LLONG_MAX / INT_MAX);
    pair* kv = malloc(n * sizeof *kv);
    if (!kv)
        return 0;

    for (int i = n; i-- > 0;) {
        kv[i].key = arr[i] * (i + 1LL);
        kv[i].value = arr[i];
    }

    qsort(kv, n, sizeof *kv, sortByValueAndIndex_comp);

    for (int i = n; i-- > 0;)
        arr[i] = kv[i].value;

    free(kv);
    return arr;
}
```